# How do I select and print the : values and , values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

How do I select and print the   `:`  separated values and the`,` separated values in pandas. Example, I want, from ( Fridge:200:1,1,1,...1) the 200 values to be printed separately and the printed sum of the 1s after the final : from the"

```
Fridge:200:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Washer:500:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
Oven:2150:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Microwave:1000:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0,0
Aircon:2000:0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Console:140:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Console:140:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Your query is unclear.

Comment: Can you add some code that you tried ? Also the desired output ?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the expected output for your sample input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, This might help you:

```
'''
Fridge:200:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Washer:500:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
Oven:2150:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Microwave:1000:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0,0
Aircon:2000:0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
TV:60:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Console:140:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Console:140:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
'''

import pandas as pd

# for your case, if you are reading the data from csv, 
# use the separator as ":" just like below
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=":", header=None)

df[3]=df[2].str.split(',',expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           0     1                                                  2     3
0     Fridge   200    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
1     Washer   500    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0   3.0
2       Oven  2150    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0   2.0
3  Microwave  1000  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0....   1.5
4     Aircon  2000    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  12.0
5         TV    60    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
6         TV    60    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
7         TV    60    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
8    Console   140    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
9    Console   140    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  24.0
```

Comment: *Do not use eval*. Better approach `df[2]=df[2].str.split(',',expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)`